# Using VSCode and Paket to add file to `.fsproj`

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, paket

I'm using VSCode and Paket to add libraries from Nuget to an F# project/`.fsproj` file.

From VSCode, I use `ctrl+shift+p` and use the command `Paket: Add Nuget Package (to current project)` and enter

```
FsVerbalExpressions version 0.4.0
```

Unfortunately, Paket fails with the following error:

```
Paket version 3.23.2.0
Adding FsVerbaExpressions 0.4.0 to 
c:...\paket.dependencies into group Main
Resolving packages for group Main:
 - FsVerbaExpressions is pinned to 0.4.0
    Package not available.
      Message: Couldn't get package details for package FsVerbaExpressions 0.4.0 on https://www.nuget.org/api/v2.
Paket failed with:
    Could not find versions for package FsVerbaExpressions on https://www.nuget.org/api/v2.
```

[I know that `FsVerbalExpressions` is available on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FsVerbalExpressions/).  I need the older version because the project I'm working on is targeted at `.NET 4.5` and the newer version of `FsVerbalExpressions` will only work with `.NET 4.6.1`.

Comment: What kind of environment are you on? I assume no VS 2015, but for  example is it possible to use nuget command line?

Comment: If you copied and pasted the error message, then you made a typo in the package name (`FsVerbaExpressions` instead of `FsVerbalExpressions`).

Comment: Yes, most probably as TDD says. I just added it via paket: `Downloading FsVerbalExpressions 0.4.0`.

Comment: And now I feel like an idiot!  Thanks for making it simple @TeaDrivenDev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typos happen.  Make sure you proofread your error messages before looking for answers that are already in front of you.